# CLion installation is complete, but cannot be started

Tags: software-design

**emm...

I passed the ToolBox to complete the software installation.As shown in figure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYYOj.png)

But when I open the CLion will display error message:**

> I use the operating system is Linux
> Specific as follows: Linux 5.18.17-amd64-desktop-community-hwe 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> Software version for: **2022.3.1** 223.8214.51
> Additional information: I installed the IDEA and Fleet is OK，started also.
> Java version for: **java 17.0.5 2022-10-18 LTS**

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot invoke (class=AtomSettingsListener, method=appStarted, topic=AppLifecycleListener)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.kt:639)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.deliverMessage(MessageBusImpl.kt:395)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.pumpWaiting(MessageBusImpl.kt:374)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.access$pumpWaiting(MessageBusImpl.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessagePublisher.invoke(MessageBusImpl.kt:433)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy45.appStarted(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeStarter$start$2.invokeSuspend(IdeStarter.kt:77)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeStarter$start$2.invoke(IdeStarter.kt)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeStarter$start$2.invoke(IdeStarter.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:89)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope(CoroutineScope.kt:264)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeStarter.start$suspendImpl(IdeStarter.kt:70)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeStarter.start(IdeStarter.kt)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.initApplicationImpl(ApplicationLoader.kt:169)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.access$initApplicationImpl(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplicationImpl$1.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.intellij.openapi.util.IconPathPatcher
    at com.mallowigi.icons.services.IconPatchersManager.fixExperimentalUI(IconPatchersManager.kt:89)
    at com.mallowigi.icons.services.IconPatchersManager.init(IconPatchersManager.kt:48)
    at com.mallowigi.icons.AtomSettingsListener.initComponent(AtomSettingsListener.kt:66)
    at com.mallowigi.icons.AtomSettingsListener.appStarted(AtomSettingsListener.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.invokeMethod(MessageBusImpl.kt:652)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.kt:625)
    ... 21 more

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.5+1-b653.23 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
/home/AaronLi/Software/ToolBox/apps/CLion/ch-0/223.8214.51/jbr
```

**Java Version**

```
java 17.0.5 2022-10-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.5+9-LTS-191)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.5+9-LTS-191, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The first time I met this kind of problem, so I didn't try to do it.
I hope to be able to get a smooth...

Answer (score 0):

OK,I successfully solved the problem.
The cause of the problem is that I didn't use before install CLion ToolBox.So there is a CLion2022.3 folder in the ./local/share/JetBrains directory，I didn't delete the file, so CLion gets an error when it starts.